# Appfabric cache (velocity) with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, appfabric

Can anyone let me know how we can use Appfabric cache (velocity) with Entity Framework.

I have already seen the article written by "Jaroslaw Kowalski" but velocity code with EF has been removed from the site now. Any help will be appreciated.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers-c0b88f32

Also how EF with Appfabric cache stays in-sync with database ?

Comment: you could see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh394143.aspx) article by Julie Lerman, it uses the same approach you outlined, but with AppFabric.